# How to create a fat32 file system on bare metal raspberry pi 4?

Tags: sd-card, bare-metal

There is some "os" tutorial for raspberry pi 4:

https://github.com/isometimes/rpi4-osdev

https://github.com/rust-embedded/rust-raspberrypi-OS-tutorials

but they did not refer to how to build a file system

there is some example of how to build a fat32 for stm32 (using fatfs)

and there is an example for raspberry pi pico of create a fat32:

https://github.com/carlk3/no-OS-FatFS-SD-SPI-RPi-Pico

so is there some tutorial of create a fat32 filesystem for pi 4?

Thanks!

Comment: `how to build a file system` ... that is independent of the hardware ... the same data would be written to a disk partition